# Generalisation of vector outer product: apply it to every column of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I have a matrix `A = [x1, x2, ..., xm]` where each `xi` is a column vector of size `[n, 1]`. So A has shape `[n, m]`. I am trying to find the covariance matrix of each column vector so that if the result is another matrix `C`, `C` has shape `[n, n, m]` and `C[:,:,i] = np.outer(xi, xi)`.

Can someone tell my how to do the above in numpy or point me to a tensor operation that I should check out?

Comment: It was recently pointed out in another SO, that `np.outer` flattens its inputs, while `np.multiply.outer` does not.

Answer (score 1):

So your `outer` loop produces:

```
In [1147]: A = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [1148]: [np.outer(A[:,i],A[:,i]) for i in range(4)]
Out[1148]: 
[array([[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 16, 32],
        [ 0, 32, 64]]), array([[ 1,  5,  9],
        [ 5, 25, 45],
        [ 9, 45, 81]]), array([[  4,  12,  20],
        [ 12,  36,  60],
        [ 20,  60, 100]]), array([[  9,  21,  33],
        [ 21,  49,  77],
        [ 33,  77, 121]])]
```

`stacking` that on the a new 1st dimension produces:

```
In [1149]: np.stack(_)
Out[1149]: 
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,  16,  32],
        [  0,  32,  64]],
    ....
        [ 21,  49,  77],
        [ 33,  77, 121]]])
In [1150]: _.shape
Out[1150]: (4, 3, 3)    # wrong order - can be transposed.
```

`stack` lets us specify a different axis:

```
In [1153]: np.stack([np.outer(A[:,i],A[:,i]) for i in range(4)],2)
Out[1153]: 
array([[[  0,   1,   4,   9],
        [  0,   5,  12,  21],
        [  0,   9,  20,  33]],

       [[  0,   5,  12,  21],
        [ 16,  25,  36,  49],
        [ 32,  45,  60,  77]],

       [[  0,   9,  20,  33],
        [ 32,  45,  60,  77],
        [ 64,  81, 100, 121]]])
```

`np.einsum` does this nicely as well:

```
In [1151]: np.einsum('mi,ni->mni',A,A)
Out[1151]: 
array([[[  0,   1,   4,   9],
        [  0,   5,  12,  21],
        [  0,   9,  20,  33]],

       [[  0,   5,  12,  21],
        [ 16,  25,  36,  49],
        [ 32,  45,  60,  77]],

       [[  0,   9,  20,  33],
        [ 32,  45,  60,  77],
        [ 64,  81, 100, 121]]])
In [1152]: _.shape
Out[1152]: (3, 3, 4)
```

broadcasted multiply is also nice

```
In [1156]: A[:,None,:]*A[None,:,:]
Out[1156]: 
array([[[  0,   1,   4,   9],
        [  0,   5,  12,  21],
      ...
        [ 32,  45,  60,  77],
        [ 64,  81, 100, 121]]])
```